# joomla rss feed make feed appear as in module

Tags: drupal, coding-style, joomla, rss, feed

I have a news feed in my joomla site as a module. I want to syndicate it in another site (drupal) for a customer. I want it to appear exactly as the module in my first site. I mean the exact styling and elements positioning. How should i do that? In few words I want the same feed box I have on my joomla site to appear on another drupal site.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are loading the feed in an iframe, you are going to have to add some CSS to the Drupal site to match the Joomla site.